# Repeat the first two rows of a table as the table header **from a template**

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I want to repeat the first two rows of a table as the table header on each page of a Word (2010) document.

I can repeat the first two rows by highlighting both rows and checking "Repeat row as table header" in the Table properties.  However, when I do this in a template and create a Word file from that template, when the table runs over two pages, it is just the one header row that repeats.  Any idea?

Just to confirm, I am using an 'example table' rather than using table styles as I realise this cannot be set in the table styles.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you have dragged/dropped the table in the template so that it is a floating object. In that case, repeating rows stop repeating. If you add rows to the table in the template and even in the template the rows don't repeat, that's probably what has happened.